# Delphi: why is the const set to this strange value, using Excel OLE interop?

Tags: excel, delphi, ole

Sorry, I'm very ingnorant and I would like to know why the const `lWBATWorkSheet` is setted at the number `-4167`.
Thanks, Jack.

```
function TForm1.SaveAsExcelFile(AGrid: TStringGrid; ASheetName, AFileName: string): boolean;
const
xlWBATWorksheet = -4167;
var
righe, colonne: Integer;
GridPrevFile: string;
XLApp, Sheet, Data: OLEVariant;
l, s: Integer;
begin
  // Prepare Data
  Data := VarArrayCreate([1, AGrid.RowCount, 1, AGrid.ColCount], varVariant);
  for l := 0 to AGrid.ColCount - 1 do
    for s := 0 to AGrid.RowCount - 1 do
      Data[s + 1, l + 1] := AGrid.Cells[l, s];
  // Create Excel-OLE Object
  Result := False;
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
  // Hide Excel
    XLApp.Visible := False;
  // Add new Workbook
    XLApp.Workbooks.Add(xlWBatWorkSheet);
    Sheet := XLApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[1];
    Sheet.Name := ASheetName;
  // Fill up the sheet
    Sheet.Range[RefToCell(1, 1), RefToCell(AGrid.RowCount,AGrid.ColCount)].Value := Data;
  // Save Excel Worksheet
    try
      XLApp.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(AFileName);
      Result := True;
    except
      ShowMessage('Fatal Error!');
    end;
    finally
    // Quit Excel
    if not VarIsEmpty(XLApp) then
    begin
      XLApp.DisplayAlerts := False;
      XLApp.Quit;
      XLAPP := Unassigned;
      Sheet := Unassigned;
     end;
    end;
   end;
```

Comment: it is the value of the Excel constant xlWBATWorksheet. Try  with an excel macro `MsgBox (xlWBATWorksheet)`

Comment: Because that's the version that the developers chose.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'd suppose the intention of the question is not `why` but where to know the needed value from.

Answer (score 3):

Adding excel2000 or excel97 to the use clause would let you get rid of the need to search and declare the constants on your own.

```
implementation
uses  excel2000;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Showmessage(Format('Unsigned %u, Signed %d', [xlWBATWorksheet , xlWBATWorksheet]));
    // will return Unsigned 4294963129, Signed -4167
end;
```

Comment: Once we do this, we can then use early binding should we so desire!

Answer (score 1):

This is an Enumeration. Probably it's this value because it was the next free value in the list.

Here's a nice list with Microsofts enumerations where you will see they started with -4098 and use the values from there on.

http://include.wutils.com/com-dll/constants/constants-Graph.htm

Answer (score 0):

implementation

uses  Excel2010;

{$R *.dfm}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).